# Galaxy S2 ICS 4.0.3 Wi-Fi connecting but not able to browse

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-2, connection-issues

In my new Galaxy GT-I9100 Android version 4.0.3 everything expect WI-Fi is  working fine. When I am connecting my wireless it's getting connected, but not able to browse the internet. I tried changing from DHCP to Static IP Address, restarted mobile/Wi-Fi router, removed the battery and checked, it's working for only a few minutes and again the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled the MAC Filter on your Router?

If you've then you should disable it or enter the MAC Adress of your S2 in the Routerconfig.